# How to inherit class w\ properties in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I'm new to Ruby i come from PHP and can't understand code from sample:

```
module Twitter
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :header, vendor: 'twitter'
    format :json
    prefix :api
```

[Example from here](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape)

Basically i need to inherit that class as following:

```
class MyAPI < Twitter::API
```

but in that MyAPI class `format`, `prefix` and `version` doesn't working and i can't understand why and no one manual or tutorial doesn't answer my question.

For example `format` is setting for api to output result in json format. In Twitter::API class it working well but in child one just doesn't apply. So i need to write this on each child classes what isn't good.

What `version` and `format` actually is? Is it variables (class properties) or it's parent class methods calls?

I was assuming that it's a calls and try in Twitter::API something like:

```
def initialize
  format :json
end
```

But get an error:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

or

```
def initialize
  self.format :json
end
```

> NoMethodError: private method `format' called for #<MyAPI>

Please be as detailed as you can.
Also can you point me to documentation where it was explained?

Comment: They are method calls, that probably set some attributes. What do you mean by "in that MyAPI class `format`, `prefix` and `version` doesn't working"? They do not raise any error, they are perfectly legal code. Please demonstrate how exactly they do not work (with code and error message or undesirable behaviour exhibited by that code).

Comment: Parenthesis are optional so `format(:json)` is the same as `format :json`.

Comment: @Amadan For example `format` is setting for api to output result in json format. In Twitter::API class it working well but in child one just doesn't apply.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` is something like

```
class API
  private_class_method def self.format(kind)
    #...
  end
end
```

Private methods in Ruby cannot be called with explicit receiver (with a dot before them), only implicit one (sending to the current value of `self`). Inside a class definition, `self` is the class being defined. This is why you can write

```
def self.format(...)
```

instead of

```
def API.format(...)
```

Thus, in your code,

```
class MyAPI < API
  format :json
  # ...
 end
```

it is calling the method `format` on the class object `MyAPI`, by virtue of inheritance from `API`, *as the class is being defined*. Looking at the Grape source, `format` will (ultimately) set a value in an instance variable. Let's simplify it to `@format` (it is not actually that, and it's inherited and not on `API`, but... simplifying for the example). Let's also make another method just to see what the value of the instance variable is.

```
class API
  private_class_method def self.format(what)
    @format = what
  end

  def self.peek_format
    @format
  end
end
```

Now let's make a subclass:

```
class SubAPI < API
end
```

Now, to set the format, we would want to use something like `API.format(:json)`, but we can't because it's private. So we'll make a context where `format(:json)` naturally goes to `API`:

```
class API
  format :json
end
API.peek_format
# => :json
```

Format is set. All seems well. Now let's see what happens with the subclass:

```
class SubAPI
  format :txt
end
SubAPI.peek_format
# => :txt
```

But,

```
API.peek_format
# => :json
```

Methods are inherited; instance variables are not. Each class instance (i.e. object of type `Class`) has its own set of instance variables, just like every other object has its own set of instance variables, not shared with other objects of the same class.

If you *really* want each subclass to do the same initialisation, you can do something like this (although it is not the best of ideas):

```
class API
  private_class_method def self.format(what)
    @format = what
  end

  def self.peek_format
    @format
  end

  # common initialisation
  private_class_method def self.initialize_class
    format :json
  end

  # whenever we get a new subclass, run the initialisation
  private_class_method def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.instance_eval do
      initialize_class
    end
  end

  # now initialise this class too
  initialize_class
end

class SubAPI < API
end

API.peek_format
# => :json
SubAPI.peek_format
# => :json
```

But I urge you against this. If you are using `MyAPI`, then you are probably not using `API` itself; you don't need to set the format (or other parameters) in it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation some basics here for me. Things now more clear. Although it's not solving my problem exactly i accept it as correct answer because it will help me to implement what i exactly want. I'm doing something like ApplicationController pattern. Not only "format" the case. I need to do some auth and other things common for all my "controllers" (like output format yet again)